# How to build an HTML table with Codeigniter 4 and Shield Permissions

Tags: php, codeigniter-4, user-permissions

**Using Codeigniter 4.3.3, Shield 1.0.0-beta.5 and MySQL**

I am sure I am over complicating this... I would like to build an html table using the auth_permissions_users table and 2 left nav tables sidebar_modules and sidebar_modules_sub.

By default, Shield likes to use Group.Permission stored in the auth_permissions_users table IE: admin.useredit, admin.useradd etc... I will be using a traditional method of controller.permission thus the reason for the other tables.

For the mast part I have this working correctly though it seems there should be an easier way... I built a function inside array_helper.php in the helpers folder. the function will split the controller.permission, group them by controller, then build the table based on what it finds. Though I said it is working, I have 2 issues:

**Using this table as column order reference:**

[image: Example of how layout should look with table column order]

**#1** - I would like to have 5 rows as shown in the table
IE: | Controller | Create | Read | Update | Delete |
This means we have to fill in any blanks if the permission is not provided to the user.
IE: If the user only has read permissions - shown in image below

**#2** - Need to figure out how to sort them in a way they will come out exactly correct in the table since they are not always entered into the database table in the same order.
IE: | Controller | Create | Read | Update | Delete |

**Data from Shield using $user->getPermissions();**

```php
Array
(
    [0] => admin.read
    [1] => usergroups.read
    [2] => usergroups.create
    [3] => usergroups.update
    [4] => usergroups.delete
    [5] => users.read
    [6] => users.update
    [7] => users.create
    [8] => activitylogs.read
    [9] => authgroups.read
    [10] => authgroups.create
    [11] => authgroups.update
    [12] => authgroups.delete
)
```

---

**What I have done so far**

---

If I use asort() and ksort(), I can **order** the array which will sort the permissions alphabetically, however if I only have one of the 4 permissions, then I have to inject the missing permission. That's when the array once again is out of order... example data before injecting missing values into the array. You can see in **activitylogs** I am missing Create, Update, Delete. Same with **admin** permission

```php
Array
(
    [activitylogs] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [controller] => activitylogs
                    [permission] => read
                )
        )
    [admin] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [controller] => admin
                    [permission] => read
                )
        )
    [authgroups] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [controller] => authgroups
                    [permission] => create
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [controller] => authgroups
                    [permission] => delete
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [controller] => authgroups
                    [permission] => read
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [controller] => authgroups
                    [permission] => update
                )
        )
    [usergroups] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [controller] => usergroups
                    [permission] => create
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [controller] => usergroups
                    [permission] => delete
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [controller] => usergroups
                    [permission] => read
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [controller] => usergroups
                    [permission] => update
                )
        )
    [users] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [controller] => users
                    [permission] => create
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [controller] => users
                    [permission] => read
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [controller] => users
                    [permission] => update
                )
        )
)
```

I created a function in an array_helper.php file to create a table "buildPermissionsTable()". I tried to comment the code as much as possible to explain what I am doing.

**array_helper.php**

```php
if (!function_exists('buildPermissionsTable')) {
    
    /**
     * Assumes Codeigniter - Shield - Creates a table row(s) to populate the Permissions Table.
     * This builds from the Shield auth_permissions_users DB Table
     * @param $user->getPermissions() should be stored like: "group.value" or "controller.permission" 
     *
     * This function will split from the "." and populate the table with:
     *      Group - Permission - Permission - Permission - Permission
     *      Controller - Permission - Permission - Permission - Permission
     *      ** Currently set to Create - Read - Update - Delete
     * 
     * @param $array = $user->getPermissions();
     * @param $permissionTable = buildPermissionsTable($array);
     * @param echo $permissionTable = build out HTML Table.
     * 
     * @return array|msg Returns a HTML Table array or `No Data` if `$array` is invalid or empty.
     * 
     * 
     */
    
        function buildPermissionsTable(array $array) 
    {
        $pTableHeader = PHP_EOL .'<table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped table-hover" style="width: 100%;">'. PHP_EOL .'<thead>'. PHP_EOL .'<tr>'. PHP_EOL .'<th><strong>'. lang('App.controller') .'</strong>:</th>'. PHP_EOL .'<th>Create</th>'. PHP_EOL .'<th>Read</th>'. PHP_EOL .'<th>Update</th>'. PHP_EOL .'<th>Delete</th>'. PHP_EOL .'</thead>'.PHP_EOL .'<tbody>'. PHP_EOL;
        $pTableFooter = PHP_EOL .'</tbody>'.PHP_EOL .'</table>';
        
        if (!$array) {
            $pTableBody = PHP_EOL .'<tr>'. PHP_EOL .'<td colspan="5" class="text-center">No Data Provided...</td>'. PHP_EOL .'</tr>'. PHP_EOL;
            return $pTableHeader . $pTableBody . $pTableFooter;
        }
        
        // This foreach loop will split the data based on the period into the first array
        // Example: array([controller] => activitylogs [permission] => read )
        $permData = [];
        foreach ($array as $key) {
            list($a, $b) = explode('.', $key);
            array_push($permData, [
                'controller' => $a,
                'permission' => $b,
            ]);
        }
        
        // Sorting the keys and values alphabetically
        asort($permData);
        

        // grouping to make the controller the index
        // Example: Array ( [activitylogs] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [controller] => activitylogs [permission] => read ) )
        
        $grouped = array_reduce(
            $permData,
            function ($carry, $item) {
              $carry[$item['controller']][] = $item;
              return $carry;
            },
            []
        );
        
        // Sorting again alphabetically - might not be needed but its free
        ksort($grouped);
    
        // Now that we have the array, lets build the HTML table
        foreach ($grouped as $key => $value):
            
            
            $pTableBody .=  PHP_EOL .'<tr>'. PHP_EOL;
            $pTableBody .= '<td><strong>'. strtoupper($key) .'</strong></td>'. PHP_EOL;
            
            $pTableBody .= '<td class="text-center '. ($value[0]['permission'] =='' ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success').'"><i class="fas '. ($value[0]['permission'] =='' ? 'fa-remove' : 'fa-check').' fa-xl"></i><br>'. $key .'.'. ($value[0]['permission'] =='' ? 'none!' : $value[0]['permission']).'</td>'. PHP_EOL;
            $pTableBody .= '<td class="text-center '. ($value[1]['permission'] =='' ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success').'"><i class="fas '. ($value[1]['permission'] =='' ? 'fa-remove' : 'fa-check').' fa-xl"></i><br>'. $key .'.'. ($value[1]['permission'] =='' ? 'none!' : $value[1]['permission']).'</td>'. PHP_EOL;
            $pTableBody .= '<td class="text-center '. ($value[2]['permission'] =='' ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success').'"><i class="fas '. ($value[2]['permission'] =='' ? 'fa-remove' : 'fa-check').' fa-xl"></i><br>'. $key .'.'. ($value[2]['permission'] =='' ? 'none!' : $value[2]['permission']).'</td>'. PHP_EOL;
            $pTableBody .= '<td class="text-center '. ($value[3]['permission'] =='' ? 'text-danger' : 'text-success').'"><i class="fas '. ($value[3]['permission'] =='' ? 'fa-remove' : 'fa-check').' fa-xl"></i><br>'. $key .'.'. ($value[3]['permission'] =='' ? 'none!' : $value[3]['permission']).'</td>'. PHP_EOL;
            $pTableBody .= '</tr>'. PHP_EOL;
        endforeach;
        
        return $pTableHeader . $pTableBody . $pTableFooter;
    }
}
```

[image: This image shows how the table currently looks]

This is how the table looks now, notice they are not in the correct order as Create-Read-Update-Delete. it should properly align with the column header:

| Controller | Create | Read | Update | Delete |

Comment: What would be the correct ordeer? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: Following the table pictured as well as the last line in this post... | Controller | Create | Read | Update | Delete |

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: Updated the original post to show what has been done, added more comments to code within function. - Hopfully this helps define the question better and what I've done so far. @NicoHaase

Comment: Also posted on [Codeigniter Site](https://forum.codeigniter.com/showthread.php?tid=87702&pid=409950#pid409950) for help...